# Type error when implementing finger trees

Tags: recursion, types, f#, infinite, finger-tree

I wanted to play around with 2-3 finger trees as described in the (Haskell) paper by [Hinze](http://www.staff.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/FingerTree.pdf) (see also this [blog](http://andrew.gibiansky.com/blog/haskell/finger-trees/)).

```
type Node<'a> =
    | Node2 of 'a * 'a
    | Node3 of 'a * 'a * 'a

    static member OfList = function
        | [a; b] -> Node2(a, b)
        | [a; b; c] -> Node3(a, b, c)
        | _ -> failwith "Only lists of length 2 or 3 accepted!"

    member me.ToList () =
        match me with
        | Node2(a, b) -> [a; b]
        | Node3(a, b, c) -> [a; b; c]

type Digit<'a> =
    | One of 'a
    | Two of 'a * 'a
    | Three of 'a * 'a * 'a
    | Four of 'a * 'a * 'a * 'a

    static member OfList = function
        | [a] -> One(a)
        | [a; b] -> Two(a, b)
        | [a; b; c] -> Three(a, b, c)
        | [a; b; c; d] -> Four(a, b, c, d)
        | _ -> failwith "Only lists of length 1 to 4 accepted!"

    member me.ToList () =
        match me with
        | One a -> [a]
        | Two(a, b) -> [a; b]
        | Three(a, b, c) -> [a; b; c]
        | Four(a, b, c, d) -> [a; b; c; d]

    member me.Append x =
        match me with
        | One a -> Two(a, x)
        | Two(a, b) -> Three(a, b, x)
        | Three(a, b, c) -> Four(a, b, c, x)
        | _ -> failwith "Cannot prepend to Digit.Four!"

    member me.Prepend x =
        match me with
        | One a -> Two(x, a)
        | Two(a, b) -> Three(x, a, b)
        | Three(a, b, c) -> Four(x, a, b, c)
        | _ -> failwith "Cannot prepend to Digit.Four!"

[<NoComparison>]
[<NoEquality>]
type FingerTree<'a> =
    | Empty
    | Single of 'a
    | Deep of Digit<'a> * FingerTree<Node<'a>> * Digit<'a>

type Digit<'a> with
    member me.Promote () =
        match me with
        | One a -> Single a
        | Two(a, b) -> Deep(One a, Empty, One b)
        | Three(a, b, c) -> Deep(One a, Empty, Two(b, c))
        | Four(a, b, c, d) -> Deep(Two(a, b), Empty, Two(c, d))

type View<'a> = Nil | View of 'a * FingerTree<'a>
```

Now I just cannot get the `viewl` function working, it complains about a type mismatch:

> Expecting a FingerTree<'a> but given a FingerTree>.
>
> The resulting type would be infinite when unifying ''a' and 'Node<'a>' FingerTree.

```
let rec viewl : FingerTree<'a> -> View<'a> = function
    | Empty -> Nil
    | Single x -> View(x, Empty)
    | Deep(One x, deeper(*:FingerTree<'a>/FingerTree<Node<'a>>*), suffix) ->
        let rest =
            match viewl deeper with
            | Nil ->
                suffix.Promote()
            | View (node(*:Node<'a>*), rest) ->
                let prefix = node.ToList() |> Digit<_>.OfList
                Deep(prefix, rest, suffix)
        View(x, rest)
    | Deep(prefix, deeper, suffix) ->
        match prefix.ToList() with
        | x::xs ->
            View(x, Deep(Digit<_>.OfList xs, deeper, suffix))
        | _ -> failwith "Impossible!"
```

I had this error before in `prepend` but was able to resolve it by adding the full type info on the function.

```
// These three/four type annotations solved the problem.
let rec prepend<'a> (a:'a) : FingerTree<'a> -> FingerTree<'a> = function
    | Empty -> Single a
    | Single b -> Deep(One a, Empty, One b)
    | Deep(Four(b, c, d, e), deeper, suffix) ->
        Deep(Two(a, b), prepend (Node3(c, d, e)) deeper, suffix)
    | Deep(prefix, deeper, suffix) ->
        Deep(prefix.Prepend a, deeper, suffix)
```

For `viewl` this doesn't seem to be enough, so I also tried adding types in the middle of the function (look for the comments). It didn't work.

I kind of understand the error and where it is coming from. Can anyone tell me how to get this working? IMHO, it should be possible, because otherwise `prepend` would also not compile. Maybe a trick like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20338032/) helps? (Don't understand it though).

---

PS: I also put the code on [FsSnip](http://fssnip.net/7QQ) for playing around in the browser.

Comment: Deep 2nd item is a `FingerTree<Node<'a>>` and `viewl` takes a `FingerTree<'a>` that implies that `'a` must be a `Node<'a>` which it cannot hence the error message

Comment: @Sehnsucht: But when removing any of `prepend`'s annotations I get the same error. And I bet the same reasoning holds there, because every tree level really has its own type. But for prepend you can make it work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Functions like `viewl` or `prepend` rely on [polymorphic recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphic_recursion): the recursive call to `prepend` takes an argument of a different type than the original call.  You can define such functions in F#, but as you discovered they require *full* type annotations (or else you get a very confusing error message).  In particular, note that the type parameters must be explicit in the function's definition (though they can typically be inferred at call sites).  So the first problem is that you need to specify `viewl<'a>` in the definition.

However, there's an extremely subtle second problem, which concerns `Digit<_>.OfList`.  Try sending the first chunk of code to F# interactive and looking at the signatures of the resulting definitions: you'll see `static member OfList : (obj list -> Digit<obj>)`, which will subsequently make it so that `viewl` can't be defined correctly.  So what happened?  You haven't given a signature to `OfList`, so it won't be a generic method (functions will be generalized, but members never will be).  But the compiler also can't infer that you intended for the input list to be of type `'a list` where the `'a` is the type's generic parameter - why would it infer this specific type rather than `int list` or `string list`, etc.?  So it chooses a boring monomorphic default (`obj list`), unless you do something in subsequent code to constrain it to a different concrete monomorphic type.  Instead, you need to add a signature to `Digit` and then everything will be fine.

Often in F# it is idiomatic to create a separate module per-type to define related functions like `ToList`, etc.  Since function definitions are generalized, this would also have avoided the `Digit` problem you face here.  That is, you could structure your code like this:

```
type Node<'a> =
    | Node2 of 'a * 'a
    | Node3 of 'a * 'a * 'a

module Node =
    let ofList = function
    | [a; b] -> Node2(a, b)
    | [a; b; c] -> Node3(a, b, c)
    | _ -> failwith "Only lists of length 2 or 3 accepted!"

    let toList = function
    | Node2(a, b) -> [a; b]
    | Node3(a, b, c) -> [a; b; c]

type Digit<'a> =
    | One of 'a
    | Two of 'a * 'a
    | Three of 'a * 'a * 'a
    | Four of 'a * 'a * 'a * 'a

[<NoComparison>]
[<NoEquality>]
type FingerTree<'a> =
    | Empty
    | Single of 'a
    | Deep of Digit<'a> * FingerTree<Node<'a>> * Digit<'a>

module Digit =
    let ofList = function
    | [a] -> One(a)
    | [a; b] -> Two(a, b)
    | [a; b; c] -> Three(a, b, c)
    | [a; b; c; d] -> Four(a, b, c, d)
    | _ -> failwith "Only lists of length 1 to 4 accepted!"

    let toList = function
    | One a -> [a]
    | Two(a, b) -> [a; b]
    | Three(a, b, c) -> [a; b; c]
    | Four(a, b, c, d) -> [a; b; c; d]

    let append x = function
    | One a -> Two(a, x)
    | Two(a, b) -> Three(a, b, x)
    | Three(a, b, c) -> Four(a, b, c, x)
    | _ -> failwith "Cannot prepend to Digit.Four!"

    let prepend x = function
    | One a -> Two(x, a)
    | Two(a, b) -> Three(x, a, b)
    | Three(a, b, c) -> Four(x, a, b, c)
    | _ -> failwith "Cannot prepend to Digit.Four!"

    let promote = function
    | One a -> Single a
    | Two(a, b) -> Deep(One a, Empty, One b)
    | Three(a, b, c) -> Deep(One a, Empty, Two(b, c))
    | Four(a, b, c, d) -> Deep(Two(a, b), Empty, Two(c, d))

type View<'a> = Nil | View of 'a * FingerTree<'a>

let rec viewl<'a> : FingerTree<'a> -> View<'a> = function
    | Empty -> Nil
    | Single x -> View(x, Empty)
    | Deep(One x, deeper, suffix) ->
        let rest =
            match viewl deeper with
            | Nil -> suffix |> Digit.promote
            | View (node, rest) ->
                let prefix = node |> Node.toList |> Digit.ofList
                Deep(prefix, rest, suffix)
        View(x, rest)
    | Deep(prefix, deeper, suffix) ->
        match prefix |> Digit.toList with
        | x::xs ->
            View(x, Deep(Digit.ofList xs, deeper, suffix))
        | _ -> failwith "Impossible!"
```

Comment: I'm on the way, so I cannot try your code. Just a quick question concerning polymorphic recursion: Is that the thing that is not possible with regular F# functions but with static class methods? Because that trick I tried.

Comment: No, both functions and members can use polymorphic recursion, you just have to make sure to fully annotate the definition.  Your code is almost completely fine as-is - just make the small changes I mention in my first two paragraphs.  I put in the code at the bottom to show a more idiomatic approach, but it's not necessary to do it this way if you're happy with your existing structure.

Comment: Thanks also for reminding me of the disadvantages of class members when it comes to type inference. I knew that let-bound functions were better, but this was kind of the other way around and did also bite.