# How to work around F#'s type system

Tags: haskell, f#

In Haskell, you can use `unsafeCoerce` to override the type system. How to do the same in F#?

For example, to implement the Y-combinator.

Comment: `:?>` maybe - could you provide a more concrete example of what you want.  Otherwise `box |> unbox` might work

Comment: for update - see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998407/how-do-i-define-y-combinator-without-let-rec

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd like to offer a different solution, based on embedding the untyped lambda calculus in a typed functional language. The idea is to create a data type that allows us to change between types α and α → α, which subsequently allows to escape the restrictions of a type system. I'm not very familiar with F# so I'll give my answer in Haskell, but I believe it could be adapted easily (perhaps the only complication could be F#'s strictness).

```hs
-- | Roughly represents morphism between @a@ and @a -> a@.
-- Therefore we can embed a arbitrary closed λ-term into @Any a@. Any time we
-- need to create a λ-abstraction, we just nest into one @Any@ constructor.
--
-- The type parameter allows us to embed ordinary values into the type and
-- retrieve results of computations.
data Any a = Any (Any a -> a)
```

Note that the type parameter isn't significant for combining terms. It just allows us to embed values into our representation and extract them later. All terms of a particular type `Any a` can be combined freely without restrictions.

```hs
-- | Embed a value into a λ-term. If viewed as a function, it ignores its
-- input and produces the value.
embed :: a -> Any a
embed = Any . const

-- | Extract a value from a λ-term, assuming it's a valid value (otherwise it'd
-- loop forever).
extract :: Any a -> a
extract x@(Any x') = x' x
```

With this data type we can use it to represent arbitrary untyped lambda terms. If we want to interpret a value of `Any a` as a function, we just unwrap its constructor.

First let's define function application:

```hs
-- | Applies a term to another term.
($$) :: Any a -> Any a -> Any a
(Any x) $$ y = embed $ x y
```

And λ abstraction:

```hs
-- | Represents a lambda abstraction
l :: (Any a -> Any a) -> Any a
l x = Any $ extract . x
```

Now we have everything we need for creating complex λ terms. Our definitions mimic the classical λ-term syntax, all we do is using `l` to construct λ abstractions.

Let's define the Y combinator:

```hs
-- λf.(λx.f(xx))(λx.f(xx))
y :: Any a
y = l (\f -> let t = l (\x -> f $$ (x $$ x))
              in t $$ t)
```

And we can use it to implement Haskell's classical `fix`. First we'll need to be able to embed a function of `a -> a` into `Any a`:

```hs
embed2 :: (a -> a) -> Any a
embed2 f = Any (f . extract)
```

Now it's straightforward to define

```hs
fix :: (a -> a) -> a
fix f = extract (y $$ embed2 f)
```

and subsequently a recursively defined function:

```hs
fact :: Int -> Int
fact = fix f
  where
    f _ 0 = 1
    f r n = n * r (n - 1)
```

Note that in the above text there is no recursive function. The only recursion is in the `Any` data type, which allows us to define `y` (which is also defined non-recursively).

Answer (score 2):

In Haskell, `unsafeCoerce` has the type `a -> b` and is generally used to assert to the compiler that the thing being coerced actually has the destination type and it's just that the type-checker doesn't know it.

Another, less common use, is to reinterpret a pattern of bits as another type. For example an unboxed `Double#` could be reinterpreted as an unboxed `Int64#`. You have to be sure about the underlying representations for this to be safe.

In F#, the first application can be achieved with `box |> unbox` as John Palmer said in a comment on the question. If possible use explicit type arguments to make sure that you don't accidentally have the wrong coercion inferred, e.g. `box<'a> |> unbox<'b>` where `'a` and `'b` are type variables or concrete types that are already in scope in your code.

For the second application, look at the [BitConverter class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.BitConverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for specific conversions of bit-patterns. In theory you could also do something like interfacing with unmanaged code to achieve this, but that seems very heavyweight.

These techniques won't work for implementing the Y combinator because the cast is only valid if the runtime objects actually do have the target type, but with the Y combinator you actually need to call the same function again but with a different type. For this you need the kinds of encoding tricks mentioned in [the question John Palmer linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998407/how-do-i-define-y-combinator-without-let-rec).