# F# Create Factorial function without recursion, library functions or loops

Tags: f#

In this [video about functional programming](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FITJMJjASUs) at 35:14 Jim Weirich writes a function to compute factorial without using recursion, library functions or loops:
[see image of Ruby code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXK9N.png)

The code in Ruby

```
fx = ->(improver) {
  improver.(improver)
}.(
   ->(improver) {
     ->(n) { n.zero ? 1 : n * improver.(improver).(n-1) }
   }
   )
```

I'm trying to express this approach F#

```
let fx =
    (fun improver -> improver(improver))(
    fun improver ->
             fun n ->
             if n = 0 then 1
             else n * improver(improver(n - 1)))
```

I'm currently stuck at

Type mismatch. Expecting a 'a but given a 'a -> 'b
The resulting type would be infinite when unifying ''a' and ''a -> 'b'

I can't seem find the right type annotation or other way of expressing the function

Edit:

*without the **rec** keyword

Comment: but it's recursion anyway

Comment: Might be something to do with the "Y-combinator" http://stackoverflow.com/a/2000006/5763971

Comment: @Alex thanks, I mean without using the rec keyword

Comment: Where did you learn F#?

Comment: https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/ Great site, understandable without a requiring a PhD in Mathematics, written in English instead of Jargon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Languages with ML-style type inference won't be able to infer a type for the term `fun improver -> improver improver`; they start by assuming the type `'a -> 'b` for a lambda-definition (for some undetermined types `'a` and `'b`), so as the argument `improver` has type `'a`, but then it's applied to itself to give the result (of type `'b`), so `improver` must simultaneously have type `'a -> 'b`.  But in the F# type system there's no way to unify these types (and in the simply-typed lambda calculus there's no way to give this term a type at all).  [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2000006/82959) to the question that you linked to in your comment covers some workarounds.  [@desco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/270929/desco) has given one of those already.  Another is:

```
let fx = (fun (improver:obj->_) -> improver improver)
         (fun improver n -> 
              if n = 0 then 1 
              else n * (improver :?> _) improver (n-1))
```

Comment: Do you know why the ruby code works without the same problems as ML-style type inference ?

Comment: @ChristophAlrich - Ruby is a dynamic language, so there are no static types at all.  This has the advantage that type annotations and unboxing operations aren't needed, but the disadvantage that the compiler will never tell you if you've applied an operation to an incompatible value (you'll get a runtime exception).

Answer (score 3):

This is cheating, but you can use types

```
type Self<'T> = delegate of Self<'T> -> 'T
let fx1 = (fun (x: Self<_>) -> x.Invoke(x))(Self(fun x -> fun n -> if n = 0 then 1 else x.Invoke(x)(n - 1) * n))

type Rec<'T> = Rec of (Rec<'T> -> 'T)
let fx2 = (fun (Rec(f ) as r) -> f r)(Rec(fun ((Rec f) as r) -> fun n -> if n = 0 then 1 else f(r)(n - 1) * n))
```

Comment: Thank you. But instead of re-defining rec - is there a way to express the function with only functions as the Ruby code? and if not why not ? (I'm very new to FP, F# and Lambda Calc)

Comment: Bahh - I want to mark your answer correct also but I chose the one explaining why the F# code doesn't work the same way better. Thanks again!